# File upload is not setting param as a File, but as a String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara

I'm testing a form with Capybara like so:

```
attach_file('csv', File.absolute_path('spec/support/test.csv'))
```

If I print out the params in the controller this way, I get:

```
{
  "csv"=>"test.csv",
}
```

However if I do it in the browser, and select a file and submit the form that way, I get the following params.

```
{
  "csv"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f90786456f8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/dd/.../T/RackMultipart20180813-8714-9t8e5.csv>, ...>
  "remotipart_submitted"=>"true", 
  "X-Requested-With"=>"IFrame", 
  "X-Http-Accept"=>"text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript, */*; q=0.01",  
}
```

Why does Capybara give me a file path `String`, instead of a `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile`? How can I get capybara to mimic an actual file upload?

Comment: @thesecretmaster Why delete your comment?

Comment: What driver and/or browser are you using with Capybara?

Comment: @ThomasWalpole `require 'capybara/poltergeist'` `Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist`

Comment: What version of Poltergeist? What version of PhantomJS? And where did you get the PhantomJS you’re using from?

Comment: @ThomasWalpole `poltergeist (1.18.0)` / `phantomjs -v 2.1.1`. I got phantomjs via brew.

Comment: Hmm, those should work together unless there is a JS widget playing with the file input which doesn’t work under PhantomJS (ES5 only). Have you tried running the test with Selenium and Chrome to narrow down whether it’s a driver or test issue?